# Filter multidimensional multilevel array to uniq

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the next probleme, i want to filter a multidimensional and multi level array with for the uniqe one.

An example:

```
Array
(
    [Home] => Array
        (
            [Kids] => Array
                (
                    [For sleeping] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sleeping Bags

                            [1] => mattress

                            [2] => mattress

                            [3] => mattress

                            [4] => Beds

                            [5] => Beds

                            [6] => Beds
[..]
```

The befored array i want to make it with the uniqe values.

Comment: Related: [Remove duplicate values from multidimensional (3+levels) array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37791484/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem. The solution for this problem is:

```
$test = Array
(
    [Home] => Array
        (
            [Kids] => Array
                (
                    [For sleeping] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sleeping Bags

                            [1] => mattress

                            [2] => mattress

                            [3] => mattress

                            [4] => Beds

                            [5] => Beds

                            [6] => Beds
[..]

foreach ($test as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        foreach ($value2 as $key3=>$value3) {
            $cat[$key][$key2][$key3]= array_unique($value3);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the fastest / shortest answer, but the code below might work for you:

```
#Function to make a multidimensional array unique

function makeUnique(&$array)
{       
    foreach($array as $key => &$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {   
            makeUnique($value);
            $value = array_unique($value);

        }
    }
    return $array;
}

#Example of your array

$exampleArray = Array(
    'Home'  => Array(
        'Kids' => Array(
            'For sleeping' => Array(
                0 => 'Sleeping Bags',
                1 =>'mattress',
                2 =>'mattress')
                )
        )
    );


#Make the array unique and print the results

makeUnique($exampleArray);
print_r($exampleArray);
```

Comment: It don't work because i have multiple keys and it delete all other keys and leave a few values and keys.

Comment: Aah ok, you mean unique values over the hole array? Not only the nested array?

Comment: Yes i want to filter just the final value  from a multidimensional array